# VSCode Intellisense shows wrong autocomplete modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylint

I have a few modules with the same structure and it seems that the VSCode Intellisense mixes them up.

This is a part of my project structure:

```
project
|-- daos
|   -- strategies
|      -- __init__.py
|      -- athena_strategy.py
|   -- __init__.py
|   -- db.py
|-- extractor
|   -- strategies
|      -- __init__.py
|      -- extractor_strategy.py
|   -- __init__.py
|   -- extractor.py
```

The problem is that the Intellisense is showing me the `athena_strategy` module instead of `extractor_strategy` when I'm trying to import `strategies` inside `extractor.py`:
[image]

This is the `settings.json` file inside `.vscode`:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/extractor",
        "${workspaceFolder}/daos",
        "${workspaceFolder}/ingester",
    ]
}
```

Is there any other configuration that I have to add in order to get the correct modules in imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using python in VS Code, its "Intellisense" function is provided by the "python" extension and language service, and the "autocomplete" content displayed by different language services is different.

1. When using "Jedi": ( `"python.languageServer": "Jedi",` in settings.json )

   [image]
2. When using "Microsoft" or "Pylance":

   [image]

   It requires us to use "`from extractor.strategies.`", "autocomplete" will display what we need. Also, in order to make the code runnable, please add "`import sys`
   `sys.path.append("./")`" at the beginning of "extractor.py".

In addition, it is recommended that you use different file and folder names, and this good programming habit can avoid many problems.

Comment: Installing the Pylance extension for the language server solved the problem. I am not sure about using different file and folder names because having a consistent structure for each module improves the readability and makes it more intuitive.